# Blueprism: how to use the replace function in a calculation stage?

Tags: regex, replace, stage, calculation, blueprism

I am reading a text from an application using BluePrism. The text has the following structure (the number varies from case to case): "Please take note of your order reference: 525". I need to be able to extract the number from the text. Looking at the calculation stage, there is a replace function: replace(text, pattern, new-text). I want to use this function to replace all alphabetic characters in my text with an empty string to return only whatever is numeric. How can I input that in the pattern? 
So I want something like this:

```
Replace([Order confirmation text ], /^[A-z]+$/, " ")
```

Also, I tried to look for a proper documentation for the VBOs that are shipped with blueprism, but couldn't find any. Does anyone know where we can get documentations for blueprism functions?

Comment: I have also tried using the Utility-Strings VBO, using the Extract Regex action with a regex \d+, but I don't get anything in my output collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Replace() function in calculate stage is the simplest possible one. It's not a regex one!

So, if the stirng is always in that format, then you can use:

```
Replace([Text],"Please take note of your order reference:","")
```

If the text is not always that standard, then you should rather use a regular expressions. To do that, you need to use an object, that will invoke a regex code.

In the standard blueprism objects, you can find:

```
Object: Utility - Strings C#
Action: Extract Regex Values
```

I think there is no Regex Replace action, by default, so if you'd like to, then you have to implement it. Below you can find a code that I am using:

```
Dim R as New Regex(Regex_Pattern, RegexOptions.SingleLine)
Dim M as Match = R.Match(Text)
replacement_result = R.Replace(Text,Regex_Pattern,replacement_string)
```

[image: Parameters]

Comment: Yep, this is also what I ended up doing. I just specified the exact text as the "pattern", and will have to use the strings utility for better solutions. thanks!

Comment: But the "Extract Regex Values" action only extracts the matched strings instead of replacing that matched string with targeted value. How to accomplish the replacement utilizing regex is still a question.

Comment: Hey, I've added regex relace code to my answer. Enjoy!

Comment: @AndrzejKaczor Thanks I found this quite useful. But R.Replace(Text,Regex_Pattern,replacement_string) gives compiler warning. (Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance)
Better user *Regex*.Replace(Text,Regex_Pattern,replacement_string)

Answer (score 0):

Quick Answer if the pre text is constant use a Mid statement then this will take out the issue the other guy had with the right. i.e.

Mid("Please take note of your order reference: 525",42,6)

If you aim for a maximum number length it will stop at the end anyway.

Answer (score -1):

A few things here:

-Your pattern isn't matching because it's looking for a constant string of letters from start to finish (`^` anchors to the beginning of the string and `$` anchors to the end).

-You're replacing the pattern with a space, not an empty string, so you'll end up with a bunch of spaces in your result even if you correct the pattern.

-You said you only want to replace alphabetic characters, but it looks like you also want to get rid of spaces and colons.

Try replacing `[A-Za-z :]+` with "".

Comment: You are right, I was adding white space instead of replacing with empty string, and yes, I only want the numbers. so right now, i have something like this: Replace([Order confirmation text ], [A-Za-z :]+, ""), and when I evaluate the expression, I get the error: Missing data: [A-Za-z :]+. So I am thinking maybe the pattern here needs to be an actual string instead of a regex.

Comment: You still need to put the forward slashes around it

Comment: Yeah, even with the forward slashes I get the same error. I think the pattern argument here expects a string input.

Answer (score -2):

Your goal is to retrieve number from string then use `Right()`:

```
Right("Please take note of your order reference: 525", 3)
```

This will return only numeric.

Regards
Vimal

Comment: `the number varies from case to case` in other words if the number is 54 or 54321 your answer is incorrect